# Why doesn't Express delete request work when a path is specify?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, database

So I can delete a data entry when using the following code below. It looks for an entry with a _id of '1' and deletes it. However, this is if the client is located at '/people'.

```
app.delete('/people', (req, res)=>{
db.collection('people').deleteOne({
    _id: '1'
},
(err, result) => {
    if(err) return res.send(500, err)
    res.send('Entry has been deleted')  
})
})
```

However, if the client then navigates to '/people/:_id' to view a data entry and tries and then tries to delete the entry from that URL path the command doesn't go through. If I try it in postman it goes through but it doesn't work in the browser.

```
app.delete('/people/:_id', (req, res)=>{
var id = (req.params.id)
db.collection('people').deleteOne({
    _id: '1'
},
(err, result) => {
    if(err) return res.send(500, err)
    res.send('Entry has been deleted')  
})
})
```

So can you only delete an entry if you haven't explicitly navigated to its location? Or am I setting up the end point incorrectly? Also one last question how would I set up multiple delete buttons. I want one button to delete one specify entry and another button to delete all entries.

If you want to view the full code base let me know in the comments. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Navigating to a URL in a browser performs a `GET` request, but your route is only set to allow `DELETE` requests (`app.delete(...)`).

There are a few ways of fixing this:

- Declare *both* a `GET` and `DELETE` route. They can use the same handler function:

  ```
  let handler = (req, res) => {
    var id = (req.params.id)
    ...
  };

  app.delete('/people/:_id', handler);
  app.get('/people/:_id', handler);
  ```
- Use [`method-override`](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override), although I'm not sure if that'll work with `GET` requests (it may require that you use `POST`).

> I want one button to delete one specify entry and another button to delete all entries.

You could use the already-mentioned `app.delete('/people', ...)` for that. Instead of deleting just one entry, you'd delete them all. So one button would request `/people/ID`, and the other button would request `/people`